# Converting NSData to NSString in Swift 3?

Tags: xcode, nsstring, nsdata, swift3

I have a function that returns certain system values. It worked fine in Swift 2.2, and I just upgraded to Xcode 8 and Swift 3, and now it's failing.

```
func ioPlatExpertDevString(_ property: String) -> String {
    // Start tapping in to the IO Service
    let ioPlatformExpertDevice:io_service_t? = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"))

    var sAnswer = "Not Found"
    let cfAnswer:AnyObject! = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(ioPlatformExpertDevice!, "\(property)" as CFString!, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeRetainedValue()
    if (cfAnswer != nil) {
        let nsAnswer = (cfAnswer as! NSString)
        sAnswer = nsAnswer.uppercased
    }

    // Close the IO Service
    IOObjectRelease(ioPlatformExpertDevice!)

    return sAnswer
}
```

Prior, I was using "CFData" instead of "AnyObject". It builds fine, but at runtime, I get the following error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFData' (0x7fff7b833ec0) to 'NSString' (0x7fff7ac32038).

Comment: For which property are you calling that function?

Answer (score 5):

**Replace**

```
let nsAnswer = (cfAnswer as! NSString)
```

**To**

```
let nsAnswer = NSString(data: cfAnswer as! Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

For more recent versions of Swift:

```
String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do **not** annotate types unless the compiler tell you to do.

For example `IOServiceGetMatchingService` returns a non-optional `io_service_t`, your optional annotation makes it worse.

`IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty` returns `Unmanaged<CFTypeRef>!` an annotation is not needed either as well as the string interpolation and the cast to implicit unwrapped optional.

`CFTypeRef` can be bridge casted to a native Swift type.

If the return type is `(NS)Data` it's most unlikely that it worked in prior versions.

This code considers `String` and `Data` if the latter can be converted to `String`.

```
func ioPlatExpertDevString(_ property: String) -> String {
  // Start tapping in to the IO Service
  let ioPlatformExpertDevice = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"))

  var sAnswer = "Not Found"
  let cfAnswer = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(ioPlatformExpertDevice, property as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeRetainedValue()
  if let cfData = cfAnswer as? Data, let answer = String(data:cfData, encoding:.utf8) {
    sAnswer = answer.uppercased()
  } else if let answer = cfAnswer as? String {
    sAnswer = answer.uppercased()
  }
  // Close the IO Service
  IOObjectRelease(ioPlatformExpertDevice)
  return sAnswer
}
```